# Can I achieve multiple dispatch between int and NSNumber?

Tags: objective-c, types, casting, type-conversion, nsnumber

I'm writing some library code, and users of the library sometimes have different opinions about which methods should use int and when to use NSNumber. I would like some way to set up a method so that either of

```
[myObject myMethod:5];
```

or

```
[myObject myMethod:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]]
```

works the same way. In Java, autoboxing makes this relatively straightforward, but I'm not aware of any way to make this happen in objective-c. Is it possible to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Objective-C does not support function/method overloading, as in C++.

Usually, if you need to support different datatypes, you will create distinct methods.
Note that you can then convert yourself the passed value, so you don't have to write (copy/paste) the same code.

For instance:

```
- ( void )methodWithInt: ( int )val
{
    [ self methodWithNumber: [ NSNumber numberWithInt: val ] ];
}

- ( void )methodWithLong: ( long )val
{
    [ self methodWithNumber: [ NSNumber numberWithLong: val ] ];
}

- ( void )methodWithNumber: ( NSNumber * )num
{
    /* Effective code */
}
```

At the end, everything will be redirected to the `methodWithNumber` method.

Comment: Obviously it depends on what you are ultimately doing with your number, but in general I lean toward funneling everything into `methodWithInt:`, as it's slightly less memory footprint.

Comment: If you need to call methodWith* millions of times, then methodWithInt could be 10x faster (or more) and it might not drop a million NSNumbers on the autorelease pool. So as long as you are sure an int is what it always will be, then as a library, you having no idea how it will be called, should lean towards methodWithInt: as the 'real' call. With a million calls the memory footprint of NSNumber would be about 12 MB or so, if the caller used autoreleased NSNumbers.

Answer (score 1):

No. Obj-C does not have auto-boxing or method overloading.

There is one facility in Obj-C that performs auto-boxing/unboxing, and that is Key-Value Coding, but it's not appropriate for situations like this.